Can a CBP officer verbally prescribe a shorter duration of stay than what’s listed on the I-94?
My mom arrived to the U.S. today on a B1/B2 visa. At the airport the CBP officer chided her for spending a lot of time in the US in the past 12 months (though never in excess of official limits) and told her she must leave the U.S. within 30 days. However when I checked her I-94 it showed the expected 6 months, with an Admit Until date of October 1st. Her passport was not stamped so that’s the only date we can cross check.

Is there a provision in U.S. immigration law for a CBP officer to verbally require a shorter length of stay? Or can this verbal warning be safely ignored and one should just follow the I-94 date? The current plan is for her to leave on June 12th and not come back for at least 6-7 months.
Update: added a more detailed travel history below for better context.
2019: 2 visits, 8 months total
2020: 1 visit, 3 months (COVID)
2021: 2 visits, 9 months total
2022: 3 visits, 8 months total
2023: 2 visits: 10 months total
2024: 2 visits, 4 months total

Note that another possible interpretation is not so much that she has to leave within 30 days, but rather that if she doesn’t and comes back following the same rhythm she will be refused entry next time. I.e. more of a warning than an actual limit. I think it would be useful to heed the advice given.

What her travel history to the US though? Has she stayed well less half of her time in the US?

@jcaron So double secret limit on entry?  Which leaves everyone guessing.

@PeterM not a secret limit, more something along the lines of “when I see your record I feel you’re near the edge, but it you stay more than 30 days this time the next guy will certainly consider you are really over the edge”.

@jcaron visited twice for 5.5 months at a time with 3 months in between

@jcaron But unless it's written down in a record it leaves it all up in the air as we have no idea what the next guy will actually do.

@JonathanReez that’s well over the limit. The official rule of thumb is that you should stay out at least as much as you were in. It’s not expressed as clearly as 90/180 in Schengen but the net effect is the same.

@jcaron the current plan is for her to leave in 2 months and come back after 6 more months. I'm debating whether to change the ticket to leave in 1 month as verbally requested.

@JonathanReez even if there is no hard limit on the I-94 I wonder if they can make notes for future inspections about what he told her. Unless she plans to not come back for a very long time (a year or two) it’s probably safer to abide with the “advice”? Let’s see what others think…

@jcaron the "rule of thumb" is a rule of thumb because it is unofficial.  The actual rule is that you must leave or apply for an extension of status before the expiration date of the I-94.  So she was in fact within the limit, not over it.

@JonathanReez So 11 months out of 14? Sounds more like living in the US with a 3 month holiday in between

@PeterM "But unless it's written down in a record" - law enforcement has to document every encounter, so there's definitely a record. When cops "let you go with a warning" - they actually document the warning. This is a similar case. Whether or not the next cop acts on it really depends on the situation the next cop finds themselves in.

@JonathanReez Ah, took me a minute to figure it out: US 5.5 months, left for 3, US 5.5 months, left for 3. So technically in the last year, 6 months in, 6 months out. Right? But over the last 17 months, 11 in, 6 out. With this 2 month trip, 13 in, 6 out; Staying out 6 months after that still won't quite balance out.

@mkennedy I will change the return ticket from January 12th to March 3rd, this should be good enough to balance it out, but ignore the warning and still leave in June.

Generally I-94 is the authority. See here:

The visitor must exit the U.S. on or before the departure date
stamped on the I-94

What I suspect happened was that the CBP officer either intended to override the default and didn't, or is trying to suggest that staying for another 6 months may lead to denial of entry on the next visit.
The CBP officers have a very wide discretion, but overriding the default probably requires some extra paperwork to document the decision that the officer ended up skipping. In the end of the day, the next CBP officer may just wave her in, or not let her in at all even if she does leave after 30 days.
I-94 defines the status, but doesn't guarantee anything in the future. She'd be within her rights to stay until October, but the CBP may deny her entry in the future if she does. The general rule of thumb is to stay outside the US at least the same amount of time as spent in the US, and your mother seems to be spending way more time in the US than expected from a temporary visitor.

Overriding the default officially requires a supervisor's approval, so it's possible that the officer didn't want to obtain that approval for some reason.

Indeed. more so denying entry. It's a hassle, so they probably don't want to actually deal with it, just make her think they did.

@phoog the entire landing interview took ~60 seconds, so definitely not enough time for any paperwork

Also possible: the CBP office was just an "unpleasant person" who felt like grunting at someone. Unfortunately I've a met a lot of these who really enjoy lording over other people and the unreasonable amount of "discretion" that they have encourages this behavior.


Is there a provision in U.S. immigration law for a CBP officer to verbally require a shorter length of stay? Or can this verbal warning be safely ignored and one should just follow the I-94 date?

The problem is that it's a false alternative. Being allowed to stay doesn't mean it cannot create issues when reentering later, especially if your mother wants to do it soon after leaving (you mentioned elsewhere that you suspect a 10-day turnaround between two long visits is what got her the warning in the first place). And even if that one officer had no way to influence any further decision or overstated their authority, the fact remains that CBP officers work off the same rulebook and had the same training. So if something appears borderline to one of them, it's not unlikely to look the same to another officer the next time around.
Ultimately if your mother does run into problems because of her long stays, it won't necessarily be because she got warned by this officer but it would mean it wasn't entirely safe to ignore him. I have no idea how likely that is or how consistent CBP is but it's not reasonable to consider that decisions are completely random and that this warning contains no information whatsoever.
